# How are root CA revocations handled?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-revocation

Considering some CA certificates are hardcoded into operating systems, I was wondering what happens when one of these hardcoded certificates is revoked (put on a revocation list for example) because of it being compromised?

Does the operating system have a system for updating it in case it is revoked? How? And how can it be updated after it has expired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As can be seen from [Can a RootCA be revoked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/can-a-rootca-be-revoked) there is no mechanism inside a [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) that a root CA gets removed. This means a mechanism outside the PKI is needed. This consists usually of an update of the trust store through update of the browser or the system which removes this certificate from the trust store or mark it as untrusted.

Such events happened in the past for example with [DigiNotar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiNotar#Issuance_of_fraudulent_certificates). This case was handled by updates to the Firefox and Chrome browsers, updates of  Microsoft Windows and of iOS and Mac OS X.